# Convert text file into dataframe with custom multiple delimiter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

i'am new to python. I have one `txt` file. it contains some data like

```
0: 480x640 2 persons, 1 cat, 1 clock, 1: 480x640 2 persons, 1 chair, Done. date (0.635s) Tue, 05 April 03:54:02 
0: 480x640 3 persons, 1 cat, 1 laptop, 1 clock, 1: 480x640 4 persons, 2 chairs, Done. date (0.587s) Tue, 05 April 03:54:05 
0: 480x640 3 persons, 1 chair, 1: 480x640 4 persons, 2 chairs, Done. date (0.582s) Tue, 05 April 03:54:07
```

i used to convert it into pandas dataframe with multiple delimiter

i tried code :

```
import pandas as pd

`student_csv =  pd.read_csv('output.txt', names=['a', 'b','date','status'], sep='[0: 480x640, 1: 480x640 , date]')

student_csv.to_csv('txttocsv.csv', index = None)`
```

Now how to convert it into pandas dataframe like this...

```
     a               b                       c           
    
2 persons    2 persons,  Done    Tue, 05 April03:54:02
```

How to convert text file into dataframe

Comment: I ran this code on the text file and it throws an error:  `Expected 67 fields in line 2, saw 73. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.` This means that the example text file is not being read correctly...  Please provide a correct dataframe or https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky to know exactly what are your rules for splitting. You can use a regex as delimiter.

Here is a working example to split the lists and date as columns, but you'll probably have to tweak it to your exact rules:

```
df = pd.read_csv('output.txt', sep=r'(?:,\s*|^)(?:\d+: \d+x\d+|Done[^)]+\)\s*)',
                 header=None, engine='python', names=(None, 'a', 'b', 'date')).iloc[:, 1:]
```

output:

```
                                      a                     b                    date
0             2 persons, 1 cat, 1 clock    2 persons, 1 chair  Tue, 05 April 03:54:02
1   3 persons, 1 cat, 1 laptop, 1 clock   4 persons, 2 chairs  Tue, 05 April 03:54:05
2                    3 persons, 1 chair   4 persons, 2 chairs  Tue, 05 April 03:54:07
```

Comment: `df.to_json()`, check the docs for the exact format you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|` in `sep` argument for multiple delimiters

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=r'0: 480x640|1: 480x640|date \(.*\)',
                 engine='python', names=('None', 'a', 'b', 'c')).drop('None', axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

                                        a                             b  \
0             2 persons, 1 cat, 1 clock,     2 persons, 1 chair, Done.
1   3 persons, 1 cat, 1 laptop, 1 clock,    4 persons, 2 chairs, Done.
2                    3 persons, 1 chair,    4 persons, 2 chairs, Done.

                     c
0  Tue, 05 April 03:54:02
1  Tue, 05 April 03:54:05
2  Tue, 05 April 03:54:07
```